# Elastalert not alerting

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastalert

I am trying to utilize a simple rule using Elastalert, and it seems to not be functioning properly. My rule is:

```
# Elasticsearch host
es_host: elasticsearch

# The elasticsearch port
es_port: 9200

name: dzd_count_zero

type: any

index: logstash-*

filter:
- term:
    project: "drop_zone_dub"
- terms:
    name: ["s3_count", "dzd_nas_pcount"]

alert:
- "email"

email:
- "myemail@m.com"
```

and when I put debug on i get:

```
elastalert:Ran dzd_count_zero from 2016-03-02 13:59 UTC to 2016-03-02 17:59 UTC: 16 query hits, 0 matches, 0 alerts sent
```

If the rule is 'any' then any query hits should be alerted on, but as you can see it is not. Any ideas?

Comment: `type: any` means "any type" in the selected indices, but the filters you defined will still apply, i.e. it's not a `match_all`. Can you verify that your filters match some documents?

Comment: From the docs it says that the filters are applied and then passed to the rule. And rule type any states: `any: The any rule will match everything. Every hit that the query returns will generate an alert.` So, if I'm getting 16 query hits, which i verified is correct using the same filter in Kibana, shouldn't I be getting 16 alarms?

Comment: So you confirm that the two filters (on `project` and `name`) you've defined in your rule currently return 16 hits? Can you show the query you've created to test that?

Comment: so I just ran the Kibana query: `project: drop_zone_dub AND (name:s3_count OR name:dzd_nas_pcount)` which returned 5 hits. And then I checked my logs at the same time: `INFO:elastalert:Ran dzd_count_zero from 2016-03-03 12:46 UTC to 2016-03-03 16:46 UTC: 5 query hits, 0 matches, 0 alerts sent`

Comment: `0 matches` that's the key, and hence why `0 alerts` sent.

Comment: But shouldn't the 'any' rule, match on all hits?

Comment: The doc states `Every hit that the query returns...`, so there is a query which is defined by your filters. Those return no hits, hence no alerts. Try removing all filters or use `query_string: *` instead, what do you see then?

Comment: My query is returning hits though, its returning 5 hits

Comment: with `query_string: *`, I produce the same result: `INFO:elastalert:Ran dzd_count_zero from 2016-03-03 13:26 UTC to 2016-03-03 17:26 UTC: 6 query hits, 0 matches, 0 alerts sent`

Comment: What this means is that there are 6 documents in that time interval but none match your filters. Do you want to share your mapping and some of the documents that are hit, so that we can find out why there are no matches?

Comment: This is incorrect, that number is with the filters. Turns out the issue had something to do with a system level problem. Changed Conda version and environment and it started working.